# How to convert data sending data through TCP from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, tcp, bytebuffer

I'd like to send some data from C++ to Java via TCP.

On Java, I will use ByteBuffer to get receiced data.
When bytebuffer.getInt(), I' like to get int data which is sent on C++.

To do this, how do I convert data on C++.

Comment: [`c++ send int as bytes`](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+send+int+as+bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into network byte order using `htons()`, `htonl()`, etc, and receive it with `ByteBuffer` or `DataInputStream`.